# Асинхронные http[s] запросы чере proxy

Tags: python, http

Появилась необходимость делать асинхронные запросы по сети через прокси, на питоне.
Прошу сообщество подсказать как это можно реализовать.

python "изучаю" третий день, просьба палками не кидать. Пытался делать запросы с использованием threading но слижком уж медленно, запросов надо посылать много.

У кого какие идеи на этот счет?

PS python 3.4

Comment: Выложите краткий пример, как вы используете threading и как посылаете запросы. Если все правильно сделать, то запросы должны идти параллельно.

Comment: def request(self,id,url):
          
          h = httplib2.Http()
          resp,content = h.request(url,'GET')

  def createTasks(self,tasks):
          threads = [];
          for i in range(len(tasks)):
              if  tasks[i]:
                  el=tasks[i]
                  threads.append(threading.Thread(target=self.request, args=(el['id'],el['url'])))
                  threads[i].start()
                  threads[i].join()
                  self.request(el['id'],el['url'])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы похоже не очень понимаете, как работает threading. Постараюсь объяснить, что происходит в вашем коде:

```
def request(self,id,url):
  h = httplib2.Http()
  resp,content = h.request(url,'GET')

def createTasks(self,tasks):
  threads = [];
  for i in range(len(tasks)):
    if tasks[i]:
      el=tasks[i]
      # Тут создается объект Thread. После создания он неактивен
      threads.append(threading.Thread(target=self.request, args=(el['id'],el['url'])))
      # Thread запускается. Это значит, что параллельно запускается еще одна нить исполнения, которая начинается с вызова request(el['id'], el['url')
      threads[i].start()
      # В главном потоке мы идем дальше (в это время параллельный поток уже работает).
      # Вызов join замораживает главный поток пока thread не завершит свою работу, т.е. request.
      threads[i].join()
      # Тут зачем-то еще раз делается request с теми же параметрами.
      self.request(el['id'],el['url'])
```

Получается ваша программа запускает поток, ждет пока он завершится, и только после этого запускает новый поток. Естественно никакого ускорения так не получится. Правильно было бы создать все потоки, запустить их, и только после этого дожидаться их завершения.
Еще у вас возможна ошибка индексации. Нельзя обращаться к последнему элементу threads по индексу i, т.к. из-за условия `if tasks[i]` Thread может создаваться не на каждой итерации.
Правильно получается примерно так:

```
def createTasks(self,tasks):
  threads = [];
  for i in range(len(tasks)):
    if tasks[i]:
      el=tasks[i]
      threads.append(threading.Thread(target=self.request, args=(el['id'],el['url'])))
      threads[-1].start()
  for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Благодарю. Стало работать в разы быстрее. 100 запросов за 5 сек с копейками. А есть ли какие то варианты как это можно еще ускорить?

Comment: Особо нет. Все зависит от ширины канала и latency до сервера. Ну и сколько запросов в секунду разрешит делать сервер.